# Facebook - posting with facebook dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-opengraph

I manage get access token from FB. 
I can post on wall. But I need to display popup window (dialog?) to allow user add comment and see what he posting (sharing).

Im confused with Open graph which I believe I use and graph API. Is the same thing? 
Bellow is my code:

```
    private string CheckAuthorization()
    {
        string app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string scope = "publish_stream,email,user_location,user_birthday";


        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
           Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
           app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
            app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


            string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

            foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                        token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }

            return tokens["access_token"];

        }
    }
```

Above code working fine Im getting access token (login popup when Im not logged and popup with information about what info will be shared).

Then I post on FB wall:

```
            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "some text to post" });
```

My question is how to get popup window before post with description what Im posting and option to add user own comment.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Can I get this dialogue without using JavaScript? Im using asp.net + MVC3.

Comment: If you would care to scroll the description page down a bit …